# 'C:\wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, windows

I want to display in a browser the load percentage of a cpu trough php.
This is the code I am using:

```
$command ="C:\\wmic cpu get loadpercentage"; 
echo shell_exec("$command 2>&1 ; echo $?" );
```

This is the output:

```
'C:\wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am I missing?

Update - 1

Change the code to allow spaces between words:
`$command ="C:\\wmic^ cpu^ get^ loadpercentage";`

```
'C:\wmic cpu get loadpercentage' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Now the entire line of code is being read, not only **'C:\wmic'**

Comment: file extension maybe?

Comment: What is `wmic`? Is it an executable file (possibly called `wmic.exe`)? A batch file (possibly called `wmic.bat`)? Something else? Are you sure it lives right in ``C:\``?

Comment: yes. If I run in the command prompt: `C:\>wmic cpu get loadpercentage`, this is what I get:` LoadPercentage
6`

Comment: This is  a kind of error when the environment system variables is not sit for the programm we are trying to call trough shell_exec(). But I am getting the same error even if I try to call  .` $command ="C:\\php^ -v"; ` And I sit php.exe inside my variables system. It works in command line.

Comment: @zwitterion, that sample command doesn't answer any of the questions asked in comments here. (a) If you type `wmic`, Windows will happily run `wmic.exe` or `wmic.bat`. PHP won't. (b) Which of the previous things gets run depends on your `%PATH%` variable, which is a list of directories to search for executables. Your `wmic` program (whatever it is really called) could be _anywhere_, and likely is _not_ in ``C:\``. Try running `where wmic` on the command line and see what it says.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe

Comment: @zwitterion, terrific. Try using `C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\WMIC.exe` instead of ``C:\`` in your command and see what happens.

Comment: now it seems that is reading. This what I get "; - Alias not found."

Comment: @zwitterion, that's because you're using Unix-style shell concepts on Windows. What output are you trying to get?

Comment: I was trying to get `loadpercentage 19` for example. That is the result when I run `C:\Windows\System32>wmic cpu get loadpercentage`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122761/discussion-between-chris-and-zwitterion).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems, both of which we explored in the comments above:

1. The actual WMIC binary is located at `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe`, not `C:\wmic`. That path needs to be used in your PHP command.
2. You are trying to use Unix-style shell concepts (redirecting `STDERR` to `STDOUT`, chaining commands with `;`, and using `echo` and `$?`) on a Windows system.

   Simply running the command without all that stuff should work:

   ```
   echo shell_exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\WMIC.exe cpu get loadpercentage");
   ```

Answer (score 6):

set path `Windows+Pausebreak` > `Advanced System Settings` > `Environment Variable` > `systme varible` > `path` > `Edit`: `C:\Windows\System32\wbem`

or

Go `C:\Windows\System32\wbem` > `wbemtest` and connect then exit.

Answer (score 0):

For windows and javascript add the location of folder wbem to path variable

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1178674/wmic-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or#comment1706201_1178758) simple edit to the `%PATH%` environment variable, worked for me.